# Best way to organize models for django Recipe app with ingredients, recipes, and components

Tags: django, django-models, model

Would love some feedback here on how to structure a new app (learning project) that helps chefs build recipes.

A recipe is a specific amount of *ingredients* (ex: 1c sugar) and/or *components* (a small collection of ingredients. ex: simple syrup, which is a recipe of 1c sugar + 1c water).

For my models, here's what I'm thinking:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    ...


class Recipe(models.Model):
    FULL = 1
    COMPONENT = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (FULL, 'Full Recipe'),
        (COMPONENT, 'Component'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=FULL)
    ...


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    ...
```

My issue is I'm not sure how to account for the component (a subset of ingredients used in multiple recipes). I've made it a `Recipe.type` since that's really what it is, but not sure how to account for that in my `RecipeIngredient` model.

I could add `component = models.ForeignKey(Recipe)` to my `RecipeIngredient` model and use either that OR ingredient. But just guessing. Anyone have a suggestion of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This looks a little bit complicated. Are you sure that chefs really want to define ingredients and amounts this way?

I would start with something as simple as this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField() # <-- Ingredients, amounts, etc.
```

Comment: Yes, I'm working with a chef and they 100% want the data structured.

Answer (score 0):

This is super late, but I found this thread doing a search for something unrelated, you may find Django's 'Through Fields' useful for what you're doing. [Django Many to Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield)

With through fields your app might look something like this.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)


class Recipe(models.Model):
    FULL = 1
    COMPONENT = 2
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (FULL, 'Full Recipe'),
        (COMPONENT, 'Component'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=FULL)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        through='RecipeIngredient',
        through_fields=('recipe','ingredient'),
    )


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
```